# Copying information from a server

Tags: c#, network-programming

We have a server with a folder of local users on the C: drive. How would i go about copying the folder from that server to my local machine. Any help at all will be appreciated. i haven"t done this kind of programming before so i have no idea where to start

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the machine the program is running on has access to that share, it's exactly the same as copying from your local folder except changing the path.

So let's for argument's sake say you want to copy from \Server\Users (where Server is the servername, users is the share name) to your local c:\userShare folder, then it's as simple as:

```
File.Copy(@"\\Server\Users",@"c:\userShare");
```

You will obviously still need to implement the logic in terms of getting all the files in the directory etc, see [here](http://xneuron.wordpress.com/2007/04/12/copy-directory-and-its-content-to-another-directory-in-c/) for an example.

If you need to give access to the machine first, have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ConnectUNCPathCredentials.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNC path (`\\server\volume\directory\file`) to server location, and use [File.Copy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)

Comment: thanks it works well on my local machine but if i try to access this server: @"\\10.4.46.219\C:\Users\Public\TestFolder"; it gives me a not supported exception.

Comment: try @"\\10.4.46.219\C$\Users\Public\TestFolder"  assuming you have rights. You might need to create an explicit share

Comment: I've tried TBohnen.jnr option but it doesn't seem to be working, do you perhaps know how to insert the credentials?